# Check to see if cell has data in Excel, then add cells to the column to the left

Tags: vba, excel

If I have the following in Excel:

```
A  B  C   (columns)
a  b  c   (data)
d  e  f   (data)
g  h  i   (data)
-  -  -   (empty)
```

and the following validation dropdown:

```
With rng.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="1,2"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
```

First I need to use vba to check to see if a cell has data, and if so add in the validation dropdown to the left in a new column/cell as follows:

```
  A  B  C  D
1,2  a  b  c
1,2  d  e  f
1,2  g  h  i
 -   -  -  -
```

Following the user selecting a value from the dropdown, I need a second macro to add in further columns either side of the existing columns depending on the value selected:

```
  A  B  C  D  E  F  G
  1  a  1  b  1  c  1  (if 1 selected from dropdown)
  2  d  2  e  2  f  2  (if 2 selected from dropdown)
  2  g  2  h  2  i  2  (if 2 selected from dropdown)
```

I am a real beginner at vba so any help is greatly appreciated.

======= EDIT ================================

I have worked out the first part of this, the rest is still proving a pain:

```
Sub changeClass()


    Dim rng As Range
    Dim r As Range
    Set rng = Range(Cells(6, 2), Cells(6, 2).End(xlDown))

    Dim rCell As Range

    For Each rCell In rng.Cells
        rCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Data"
    Next rCell

    For Each rCell In rng.Cells
        With rng.Offset(0, -1).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=$A$1:$A$3"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    Next rCell


End Sub
```

And also how to insert new columns, but can't insert new data:

```
Sub newColumn()


    Dim rng As Range
    Dim crng As Range
    Dim r As Range

    With ActiveSheet
        LastCol = .Cells(5, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With

    Set rng = Range(Cells(6, 1), Cells(6, 1).End(xlDown))
    Set crng = Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(5, LastCol))
    Set drng = Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(4, LastCol))


    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim cCell As Range
    Dim dCell As Range


    For Each rCell In rng.Cells

            For Each cCell In crng.Cells
                cCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value = "columnMark"
            Next cCell

    Next rCell

    For Each dCell In drng.Cells

            If dCell.Value = "columnMark" Then
            dCell.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Insert
            End If
            dCell.Value = ""

    Next dCell


End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried various things; xlLeft was one I put in various combinations, Offset(0, -1) was another but I couldn't figure out how to apply it to the whole column with data cells. Nothing seems to work for me.

Comment: Would this be a big thing to sort out in your opinion? Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need all that dynamic creation of columns? Is it acceptable to start off with 7 columns, have your data in columns `B`, `D` and `F` and a drop-down in the cells in column `A`, and then have columns `C`, `E` and `G` follow suit with column `A`? You can achieve that without any VBA.

Comment: Is Excel the proper tool for what you're trying to do?  Perhaps a database would be better, such as Microsoft Access?

Comment: Unfortunately in this case the number of columns can vary so there is no way to say for sure how many there will be. Also the need for Excel is unavoidable as this is what the end user will have, I can't get them to use another program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an example. Paste to sheet class module where your data resides. The procedure Worksheet_Change is triggerd on all changes in the sheet so maybe the code should validate if the 'Target' intersects with validated range and if not then exit the procedure. And if you change the selection in validation combo more then once then it will not remove the previous settings so ... it is just an example :-).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim i As Byte
    Dim lastColumn As Byte
    Dim firstColumn As Byte
    Dim actualColumn As Byte

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set targetSheet = Target.Worksheet

    With targetSheet

        firstColumn = Target.Offset(columnoffset:=1).Column
        lastColumn = .Cells(Target.Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        actualColumn = firstColumn

        For i = firstColumn To lastColumn
            If (.Cells(Target.Row, actualColumn).Value <> "") Then

                ' if next cell isn't empty insert new one
                If (.Cells(Target.Row, actualColumn + 1).Value <> "") Then
                    .Cells(Target.Row, actualColumn + 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
                End If

                .Cells(Target.Row, actualColumn + 1).Value = Target.Value
                actualColumn = actualColumn + 2

            Else
                actualColumn = actualColumn + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that really helped me to get it up and runnning!! I really appreciate the time you spent, many thanks.